# CSS float left, without wrapping and fixed size

Tags: css, css-float, css-position

I have a container called timerow, which is as big as its parent. Within it I position times, so it is clear what a distance means in the boxes above it. Problem is, that `float: left;` works along with margin in % perfectly, but the last element is always wrapped. I cannot make the container wider, since then the margins in % are off.

I also tried `display: inline-block;` without success (since the whitespaces alter the positioning agian) and flexbox, which I also provided. Flexbox is quite close, but when I scale everything to small, or add another time-label (another  tag) it is not just placed on the far right, but it changes the width of the container and alters the positioning again.

My intended outcome is that all tags are positioned relative to their left neighbor as a fraction of the width of the timerow (since I calculate that % value) and any overflow is just visible in the same row and overflows the box to the right.

I've provided a minimal [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hynsockw/10/).

```
body {
  background-color: #DDD;
}

.block {
  display: block;
  background: #ccc;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: .75em;
  float: left;
}

.block:nth-child(n+2) {
  margin-left: 0.5%;
}

.barchart {
  grid-area: all;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns:
  [viewport-start] minmax(9px, 1fr)
  [container-start] minmax(20em, 35em)
  [container-end] minmax(9px, 1fr) [viewport-end];
  grid-auto-rows: 30px;
}

row {
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  grid-column: container;
  grid-row: span 4;
  line-height: 120px;
  text-align: center;
}

timerow {
  grid-column: container;
  grid-row: span 1;
  line-height: 16px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
}

timerow a {
  height: 20px;
  width: 40px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #919191;
  text-align: center;
  background: #fff;
}

timerow a:first-child, timerow2 a:first-child {
  margin-left: -21px;
}

timerow2 {
  grid-column: container;
  grid-row: span 1;
  line-height: 16px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}
timerow2 a {
  height: 20px;
  width: 40px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #919191;
  text-align: center;
  background: #fff;
  float: left;
}
```

and the html

```
<div class="barchart">
  <row style="animation: none;width:100%;">
    <a style="width:28.9444444444%;" class="block"></a>
    <a style="width:63.805555555%;" class="block"></a>
    <a style="width:6.25%;" class="block"></a>
  </row>
  
  <timerow>
  <a>00:00</a>
  <a style="margin-left:calc((28.94444 + 0.25)*1% - 40px);">07:30</a>
  <a style="margin-left:calc((63.8055 + 0.5)*1% - 40px);">22:30</a>
  </timerow>
  
  <timerow>
  <a>00:00</a>
  <a style="margin-left:calc((28.94444 + 0.25)*1% - 40px);">07:30</a>
  <a style="margin-left:calc((63.8055 + 0.5)*1% - 40px);">22:30</a>
  <a>24:00</a>
  </timerow>
  
    <timerow2>
  <a>00:00</a>
  <a style="margin-left:calc((28.94444 + 0.25)*1% - 40px);">07:30</a>
  <a style="margin-left:calc((63.8055 + 0.5)*1% - 40px);">22:30</a>
  <a>24:00</a>
  </timerow2>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid this add a negative margin-right to the last element so that its width is not counted in the total width and it can be kept on the first row (but can overflow):

```
timerow a:last-child, timerow2 a:last-child {
  margin-right: -40px;
}
```

Full code:

```css
body {
  background-color: #DDD;
}

.block {
  display: block;
  background: #ccc;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: .75em;
  float: left;
}

.block:nth-child(n+2) {
  margin-left: 0.5%;
}

.barchart {
  grid-area: all;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns:
  [viewport-start] minmax(9px, 1fr)
  [container-start] minmax(20em, 35em)
  [container-end] minmax(9px, 1fr) [viewport-end];
  grid-auto-rows: 30px;
}

row {
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  grid-column: container;
  grid-row: span 4;
  line-height: 120px;
  text-align: center;
}

timerow {
  grid-column: container;
  grid-row: span 1;
  line-height: 16px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
}

timerow a {
  height: 20px;
  width: 40px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #919191;
  text-align: center;
  background: #fff;
}

timerow a:first-child, timerow2 a:first-child {
  margin-left: -21px;
}
timerow a:last-child, timerow2 a:last-child {
  margin-right: -40px;
}

timerow2 {
  grid-column: container;
  grid-row: span 1;
  line-height: 16px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}
timerow2 a {
  height: 20px;
  width: 40px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #919191;
  text-align: center;
  background: #fff;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="barchart">
  <row style="animation: none;width:100%;">
    <a style="width:28.9444444444%;" class="block"></a>
    <a style="width:63.805555555%;" class="block"></a>
    <a style="width:6.25%;" class="block"></a>
  </row>
  
  <timerow>
  <a>00:00</a>
  <a style="margin-left:calc((28.94444 + 0.25)*1% - 40px);">07:30</a>
  <a style="margin-left:calc((63.8055 + 0.5)*1% - 40px);">22:30</a>
  </timerow>
  
  <timerow>
  <a>00:00</a>
  <a style="margin-left:calc((28.94444 + 0.25)*1% - 40px);">07:30</a>
  <a style="margin-left:calc((63.8055 + 0.5)*1% - 40px);">22:30</a>
  <a>24:00</a>
  </timerow>
  
    <timerow2>
  <a>00:00</a>
  <a style="margin-left:calc((28.94444 + 0.25)*1% - 40px);">07:30</a>
  <a style="margin-left:calc((63.8055 + 0.5)*1% - 40px);">22:30</a>
  <a>24:00</a>
  </timerow2>

</div>
```

A better solution would be to consider 0 width element and all your calculation will be easier:

```css
body {
  background-color: #DDD;
}

.block {
  background: #ccc;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: .75em;
  float: left;
}

.block:nth-child(n+2) {
  margin-left: 0.5%;
}

.barchart {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns:
  [viewport-start] minmax(9px, 1fr)
  [container-start] minmax(20em, 35em)
  [container-end] minmax(9px, 1fr) [viewport-end];
  grid-auto-rows: 30px;
}

row {
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  grid-column: container;
  grid-row: span 4;
  line-height: 120px;
  text-align: center;
}

timerow {
  grid-column: container;
  line-height: 16px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  display: flex;
}

timerow a {
  height: 20px;
  width: 0;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  position:relative;
}
timerow a::before {
  content:attr(data-time);
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:50%;
  transform:translateX(-50%);
  background: #fff;
  color: #919191;
}
```

```html
<div class="barchart">
  <row style="animation: none;width:100%;">
    <a style="width:28.9444444444%;" class="block"></a>
    <a style="width:63.805555555%;" class="block"></a>
    <a style="width:6.25%;" class="block"></a>
  </row>
  
  <timerow>
  <a data-time="00:00"></a>
  <a style="margin-left:calc((28.94444 + 0.25)*1%);" data-time="07:30"></a>
  <a style="margin-left:calc((63.8055 + 0.5)*1%);" data-time="22:30"></a>
  </timerow>
  
  <timerow>
  <a data-time="00:00"></a>
  <a style="margin-left:calc((28.94444 + 0.25)*1%);" data-time="07:30"></a>
  <a style="margin-left:calc((63.8055 + 0.5)*1%);" data-time="22:30"></a>
  <a style="margin-left:calc((6.25 + 0.5)*1%);" data-time="24:00"></a>
  </timerow>
  
    <timerow style="background:rgba(0,0,0,0.8)">
  <a data-time="00:00"></a>
  <a style="margin-left:calc((28.94444 + 0.25)*1%);" data-time="07:30"></a>
  <a style="margin-left:calc((63.8055 + 0.5)*1%);" data-time="22:30"></a>
  <a style="margin-left:calc((6.25 + 0.5)*1%);" data-time="24:00"></a>
  </timerow>

</div>
```

Comment: Wow, that is a cool solution. Albeit it seems a bit hacky, since it works only on the last element. Since this is a UI actually, I don't know how many labels there will be and at best they are positioned "as far left as possible without overlap, but if there would be overlap just place them aside, disregarding the total width". I've almost given up on that, so if there is no wonder happening I will accept your answer soon.

Comment: @mike it's not really hacky and it need to be applied to only the last element to avoid pulling other element. If you apply it to other element then you need to update your calculation to consider it. Remember that the total is: all margin + width = 100% of parent width

Comment: Oh, yeah, I see. But if there are 2 elements, that are far on the outside, I would need to take both of them as negative margins to keep the width at 100%. Then I need to check, wether something overflows or not, right? And this I cannot easlity do with only CSS+HTML, correct?
As far as I see this is actually a better solution that I thought, but I am a bit afraid that some placements will fail due to them being close to the end, but not the last item.

Comment: Thank you for this wonderful solution. I would have never come up with such trickery. CSS entails so many inherited "features" that it is really hard to know when to use what. This is exactly what I want, thank you!